# Is child-theme required when modyfing "Appearence > Editor"?

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-customizer, visual-editor

I'm using the block theme "Twenty Twenty-Three" and I've modified its appearance by doing some custom editions through "Appearence > Editor".

Now, will I lose all those changes if the theme auto-updates itself?

What's the way to go in these cases when you modify the theme through the block editor?

- Should I create a child-theme?
- Just disable auto-updates to prevent the theme from updating by itself?

Answer (score 1):

Preventing a theme from updating itself should never be the solution. Updates may address critical security issues and ensure the compatibility between the theme and WordPress version.

If you made the changes via "Appearence > Customizer" you should be fine when the theme is updated, as long as the developers did their job right.